# AngularJS Scope Add value to a model

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, express

I am working a submit form and I have a hidden input field. I want to set the value with AngularJS, however it will be sent with the form, so it looks like this:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="formData.articleId">
```

How exactly can I put a value to it with AngularJS? I tried adding ng-value="article._id" to it which added a value field with the id of the article, but it did not parse on submit.

I also tried grabbing this model with AngularJS, but again it did not work:

```
$scope.formData.articleId = data.article._id;
```

It said: Can not find articleId of undefined

Am I using a wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$scope.formData = { articleId: data.article._id };
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the angular implementation of Form rather than relying on a normal submit with an angular interpolated value

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form